# Look up a specific value based on the total number from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

A data frame contains 3 columns of city, purpose and budget. Each city has different purposes and its budget. I am using dplyr to find the city with the highest total budget as following:

```
total_expend <- df %>%
   group_by(city) %>%
   summarise(., highest.total.budget = sum(budget)) %>%
   arrange(., desc(highest.total.budget))
```

The result is a data frame with columns of city and highest.total.budget.

Now, I want to get the purpose associated with the highest.total.budget. I am not sure how to get it.

Can any please advise? Truly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should `group_by` `city` as well as `purpose`, `sum` the total `budget` and select the row with maximum value in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(city, purpose) %>%
  summarise(highest.total.budget = sum(budget)) %>%
  slice(which.max(highest.total.budget))
  #Can also use `top_n` instead of `slice`
  #top_n(1, highest.total.budget)
```

If you have only 1 row for each `purpose` in each `city` then you don't need `summarise`, you can directly get the row with maximum `budget`.

```
df %>% group_by(city, purpose) %>% slice(which.max(budget))
```